# How do I get date range from timestamps?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the "Most viewed products" for the past 7 days.

My database is `product_views` and has the following 3 fields:

`product_id`, `IP`, `ViewStamp`

The stamp type is `timestamp` and default is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. So they are formatted like so: `2014-02-02 22:24:54`.

How do I group `product_id` that has the most rows/count for a given range of days? I can't seem to get this query even remotely correct.

Thank you for any help. I hope I explained this properly.

Comment: What SQL engine are you using? Show something, anything..

Comment: If you set up an sqlfiddle then it would be easier for people to help you, I think you are looking for a `GROUP BY product_id HAVING ViewStamp BETWEEN XXXX AND XXXX` but without details of what sql server etc I cannot confirm that. On a non functional note, it would normally make sense to keep a consistent naming convention for your columns of underscores between_words or WordCapitalisation

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. This is what PhpMyAdmin says: Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.1.72-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPLv2)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
Web server

cpsrvd 11.40.1.11
Database client version: libmysql - 5.0.96
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(1) as c 
FROM product_views
WHERE ViewStamp BETWEEN '2014-02-02 22:24:54' AND '2014-10-02 22:24:54'
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That gives you the product id that has the maximum count for that range

**Edit:**

> Is it possible to ask SQL to display the last 7 days instead of typing in the actual range manually?

Yes

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(1) as c 
FROM product_views
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), ViewStamp) <= 7
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Is it possible to ask SQL to display the last 7 days instead of typing in the actual range manually?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Hanky! The first query worked. The second one returned invalid argument. THis is a great start for me, thank you.

Comment: Nevermind. I just realized there are 2 "WHERE"'s. Removed one and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cheers, happy programming :)